# Orchard CMS: (Error) "There is no build provider registered for the extension. '.dll'

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

One of my custom modules is generating the following error:

> Orchard.Environment.DefaultBuildManager - Default - Error when compiling assembly under ~/Modules/CustomModule/bin/MvcJqGrid.dll.
>   System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): There is no build provider registered for the extension '.dll'. You can register one in the  section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.

As the error message suggests, I tried registering the `.dll` extension to my `web.config` as follows:

```
<buildProviders>
    <add extension=".csproj" type="Orchard.Environment.Extensions.Compilers.CSharpExtensionBuildProviderShim"/>
    <add extension=".dll" type="Orchard.Environment.Extensions.Compilers.DefaultExtensionCompiler"/>
</buildProviders>
```

But this didn't solve the issue. Maybe I'm using the wrong `Compilers` member function, and if so, I'm not sure what is the correct one.

I also tried out a suggestion from Orchard user forum that I disable the dynamic compilation of modules and I tried it with no success. Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: What does the logs say?

Comment: And what does this module do? (never seen anything like it, but I'd compare the project file with that of another module, to try to spot the anomaly)